# A simple publish/subscribe system using an event emitter

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is from the book **Node.JS in Action**, chapter 3, example 11. Page 52.

```
var events = require('events');
var net = require('net');


var channel = new events.EventEmitter();
channel.clients = {};
channel.subscriptions = {};

//Add a listener for the join event that stores a user’s client object, 
//allowing the application to send data back to the user.

channel.on('join', function(id, client) {
    console.log('join fired');
    channel.clients[id] = client;
    this.subscriptions[id] = function(senderId, message) {
        console.log('broadcast fired');
            //ignore data if it’s been directly broadcast by the user.
            if (id != senderId) {
                this.clients[id].write(message);
            }
        }
        //Add a listener, specific to the current user, for the broadcast event.
    this.on('broadcast', this.subscriptions[id]);

});

var server = net.createServer(function(client) {
    var id = client.remoteAddress + ':' + client.remotePort;
    client.on('connect', function() {
        console.log('connect fired');
        //Emit a join event when a user connects to the server, specifying the user ID and client object.
        channel.emit('join', id, client);
    });
    client.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('data fired');
        data = data.toString();
        //Emit a channel broadcast event, specifying the user ID and message, when any user sends data.
        channel.emit('broadcast', id, data);
    });
});
server.listen(8888);
```

It stats that with this chat application:

> "If you open up a few command lines, you’ll see that anything typed in
>   one command line is echoed to the others."

I added the console.log() events to try and debug what was going on. The only log is get is the 'data fired' when sending a message. I'm able to launch the server, and connect to it via telnet, but any messages entered do not echo to any of the clients (including the client sending the message).

Can anyone shed some light on:

1. Why this doesn't work
2. Whether this is efficient or recommended code structure
3. How it can be refined/corrected

Comment: can you give me documentation on the join and broadcast listener

Comment: this is the function described in its entirety. The join event is emitted on connect for the client object, the broadcast even is emitted when data data is passed from the client. These two functions are at the bottom, within net.createServer();

Comment: This is the closest I get http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_connect

Comment: ahha, sorry i get it these are custom events, mom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `connect` event for incoming sockets (passed to the `createServer()` callback). When the callback is called, the socket is already connected. So this is an error in the book then.

You should also be careful of `this` usage.

IMHO here is a better example:

```
var events = require('events');
var net = require('net');

var channel = new events.EventEmitter();
channel.clients = {};
channel.subscriptions = {};

channel.on('join', function(id, client) {
  channel.clients[id] = client;
  channel.subscriptions[id] = function(senderId, message) {
    if (id !== senderId)
      channel.clients[id].write(message);
  }
  channel.on('broadcast', channel.subscriptions[id]);
}).on('leave', function(id, client) {
  // cleanup on client disconnect
  console.log('user ' + id + ' has left');
  delete channel.clients[id];
  channel.removeListener('broadcast', channel.subscriptions[id]);
  delete channel.subscriptions[id];
});

var server = net.createServer(function(client) {
  var id = client.remoteAddress + ':' + client.remotePort;

  console.log('user ' + id + ' has joined');

  channel.emit('join', id, client);

  client.on('data', function(data) {
    channel.emit('broadcast', id, data.toString());
  }).on('close', function() {
    channel.emit('leave', id, client);
  });
});
server.listen(8888);
```

A further improvement would be to have only one `broadcast` event handler which loops over all connected sockets instead of adding a new `broadcast` event handler for every single socket.

Comment: "You should also be careful of >>this<< usage." Can you illustrate this by an example. Or a link where I can find an explanation. Thank you!